# JanusGraph with Hbase 2.0.x with 2.1.x

Tags: hbase, janusgraph

I'm trying to figure out how i can plug janusGraph with Hbase 2.0.x or 2.1.x

I've seen in https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/915 that it's possible in the release 0.3.1 but not enabled in default.

I've tried to test it put i'm stuck during hbase tables creation with :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Admin.createTable(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/HTableDescriptor;)V
>       at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseAdmin1_0.createTable(HBaseAdmin1_0.java:117)
>       at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.createTable(HBaseStoreManager.java:780)
>       at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.ensureTableExists(HBaseStoreManager.java:744)
>       at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getLocalKeyPartition(HBaseStoreManager.java:536)
>       at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getDeployment(HBaseStoreManager.java:375)
>       at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getFeatures(HBaseStoreManager.java:417)
>       at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1256)
>       at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:160)
>       at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:131)
>       at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:121)
>       at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory$Builder.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:260)

how can i enable the Hbase 2.0 support ?

here is my code sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws BackendException {
        JanusGraph graph = JanusGraphFactory.build()
                .set("storage.backend", "hbase")
                .set("gremlin.graph", "org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory")
                .set("storage.hostname", "vmdev")
                .set("cache.db-cache", "true")
                .set("cache.db-cache-clean-wait","20")
                .set("cache.db-cache-time","180000")
                .set("cache.db-cache-size", "0.5").open();
        GraphTraversalSource g = graph.traversal();
        if (g.V().count().next() == 0) {
            tracer.info("empty graph, building DM");
            buildDM(graph);
        }
        System.exit(0);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to use the latest release? The last release notes states, they support HBase 2.1 https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/version-compat.html

About 2.0 I'm not sure, but I'm going to test it. We had some previous runs againts HBase 2.0, my colleague claims, it worked...

Comment: I'm glad you succeeded, we are using Hadoop 3, Kerberized HBase 2.0. Have a nice day!